# How can I add more classes for this code?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code on my site:

```php
<?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item): ?>
<li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even" ; if(count($items)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; ?>">
```

Which currently results in:

```html
<ul>
<li class="even">
<li class="odd">
<li class="even">
<li class="odd">
<li class="even">
<li class="odd">
<li class="even lastItem">
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is adding more classes so the result would be something like this:

```html
<ul>
<li class="even">
<li class="odd">
<li class="alt">
<li class="mart">
<li class="tara">
<li class="sono">
<li class="even">
<li class="odd">
<li class="alt">
<li class="mart">
<li class="tara">
<li class="sono">
<li class="even lastItem"></ul>
```

This means instead of 2 li Repetition, to be 6 li's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare an array of classnames, then in the foreach loop you echo one element of this array

```
<?php 
$classNames = array('even', 'odd', 'alt', 'mart', 'tara', 'sono');
foreach ($items as $key=>$item){ ?>
<li class="<?php echo $classNames[($key%count($classNames))]; if(count($items)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

I havent tested it but i think it should work

Edit: changed the evaluation of the index of classNames so you can just add more classnames into the array and it works automatically:

```
$classNames[($key%count($classNames))]
```

Comment: thank you very much ...
i just made a litle edit and this is the code that works fore me :

 <?php
   $classNames = array('even', 'odd', 'alt', 'mart', 'tara',  'sono');
    foreach ($items as $key=>$item): ?>
<li class= " <<?php echo $classNames[($key%count($classNames))]; if(count($items)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; ?>">

Comment: i deleted this tag that is after the foreach and on the end  : {